# netlogo gis:apply-coverage: NaN error

Tags: gis, netlogo

I am trying to apply the polygon feature attribute of a zone code from the shape file to the patches.  It should be easy enough with `gis:apply-coverage`, but the value prints out as `NaN` for all the patches (should be either 0,1,2,3... the value of the `Zone_Code` attribute).

I have already tried changing the minimum threshold value to 0.000001, and the zones are fairly large, so I don't think that is the problem. The rest of the shape files have worked with no problems, although I haven't used apply-coverage with them. I'm using Netlogo version 5.3

code:

```
gis:set-coverage-minimum-threshold 0.000001

gis:apply-coverage zones-dataset "ZONE_CODE" landuse_type 

ask patches
  [ print landuse_type ]
```

Answer (score 0):

It does seem like that should work if your shapefile polygons are covering some of your patches. Have you checked that the loaded zone shapefile has the correct projection/envelope etc? If the shapefile is offset from the NetLogo world it may not overlay any patches. You could quickly confirm that your shapefile is at the very least intersecting your patches:

```
ask patches gis:intersecting zones-dataset [
    set pcolor blue
    ]
```

If that doesn't work, maybe your world-envelope and the envelope of "zones-dataset" do not overlap. Otherwise, your code looks fine and worked for me using a made-up polygon shapefile.

Comment: I have a similar problem with Netlogo 6.2.2. I have used your intersection suggestion and it does paint the patches blue, so it is correctly projected

Comment: @JavierSandoval - are you getting NaN values only in patches that are not covered by the polygon (or that are only partially covered)?